# Having issues resolving a SNIMissingWarning warning

Tags: python, vagrant, virtual-machine

So I'm currently working with Vagrant VM and am running into an SNIMissingWarning error when I run my script.

After doing some research, I found that the following command should be used to counter this:

```
sudo apt-get install pyopenssl ndg-httpsclient pyasn1
```

but when I run that, i get the following error:

```
vagrant@precise64:/vagrant/RayHudsonBot$ sudo apt-get install pyopenssl ndg-httpsclient pyasn1
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package pyopenssl
E: Unable to locate package ndg-httpsclient
E: Unable to locate package pyasn1
```

I'm not sure what could cause this and I'm quite new to VMs so I'm a bit stuck. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: can you run `sudo apt-get update` before you install any packages see if it helps

Comment: will do once i'm back at my home computer.

Comment: @FrédéricHenri same error after i run that.